# Can I use map coercion in groovy to mock a class with a constructor that has parameters?

Tags: groovy, mocking, coercion

**Java example classes under test**

```
public class Sample {
    public void printPie() {
        System.out.println("Pie.");
    }
}

public class SampleCont {
    String _PIE;

    public SampleCont() {
        _PIE = "pie";
    }
    public void printPie() {
        System.out.println(_PIE);
    }
}


public class SampleContArg {
    String _PIE;

    public SampleContArg(String pie) {
        _PIE = pie;
    }
    public void printPie() {
        System.out.println(_PIE);
    }
}
```

**The groovy test class**

```
public class TestPie extends GroovyTestCase{

    void test_Sample()
    {
        def mock = [printPie: {print "NotPie"}] as Sample
        mock.printPie()
    }

    void test_SampleCont()
    {
        def mock = [printPie: {print "NotPie"}] as SampleCont
        mock.printPie()
    }

    void test_SampleContArg()
    {
        def mock = [printPie: {print "NotPie"}] as SampleContArg
        mock.printPie()
    }
}
```

The first two tests compile and run fine. The latter test doesn't run due to an exception:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at SampleContArg_groovyProxy.<init>(Script1.groovy:4)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.MetaClassHelper.doConstructorInvoke(MetaClassHelper.java:595)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.doConstructorInvoke(MetaClassImpl.java:2359)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeConstructor(MetaClassImpl.java:1255)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeConstructor(MetaClassImpl.java:1185)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeConstructorOf(InvokerHelper.java:809)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeNewN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:230)
    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:9)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:543)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:518)
    at groovy.util.ProxyGenerator.instantiateAggregate(ProxyGenerator.java:201)
    at groovy.util.ProxyGenerator.instantiateAggregateFromBaseClass(ProxyGenerator.java:70)
    at groovy.util.ProxyGenerator.instantiateAggregateFromBaseClass(ProxyGenerator.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.asType(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:3811)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ReflectionMetaMethod.invoke(ReflectionMetaMethod.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.NewInstanceMetaMethod.invoke(NewInstanceMetaMethod.java:54)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:230)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:912)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:756)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokePojoMethod(InvokerHelper.java:766)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:754)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:170)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.asType(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:622)
    at com.hp.vse.cp.cli.agentless.ssh.TestPie.test_SampleContArg(TestPie.groovy:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:154)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:127)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:118)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:208)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestReference.run(JUnit3TestReference.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:196)
```

In the case of the third class above, can I still use groovy map coercion to mock the class? If so, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8):

There is the method ProxyGenerator.instantiateAggregateFromBaseClass that be able to accept constructor arguments. But unfortunately, the as operator will not call it for you.

So, the answer is no, at the moment.

FYI, "as" will invoke one of DefaultGroovyMethods.asType() methods, but none of them calls the instantiateAggregateFromBaseClass you wanted.

Comment: As an extension to this question. Can we use closure coercion to achive a mock method using paramters?