# Easy mocking objects in groovy when the class to mock has no zero-argument constructor

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, mocking

let's say I have a self written groovy class `Person` with a constructor `Person(String name)` and some methods methods e.g. `String greeting(String text)`. Instances of this `Person` class are used in other classes, so I want to create mock objects of this `Person` class for unit testing. Often only one method is called, so I want to create a mock object and give it the method I need and nothing else. So i try it like that:

```
 Person mockedPerson = [greeting: {String text -> "This mock fooled you! ($text)"}] as Person
```

But it works only if `Person` has a zero-argument constructor. If it for example only has the constructor `Person(String name)` then I get the following error:

```
Caught: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Error casting map to Person, Reason: null
```

What do I have to do to mock classes that do not have zero-argument constructors?

Comment: What kind of testing framework are You using? Is should support creating mocks itself.

Comment: Related question: [Looks like this feature is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600512/can-i-use-map-coercion-in-groovy-to-mock-a-class-with-a-constructor-that-has-par)